# Maven Build Process - how to exclude pom file from jar?

Tags: maven, jar

`mvn package` seems to include, by default, the pom file too in the jar file. For my use case I don't want this `pom.xml` in the packaged jar. How can I achieve this??

Comment: Why don't you want it?

Comment: @JFabianMeier, i see no purpose of it. I don't want the client to see my `pom.xml`. For this use case, I have the dependencies bundled in to the jar's lib directory. So the jar will work fine as it has the dependencies and the pom.xml is not required for execution.

Comment: I would just keep it. It is standard to have the POM in the JAR, and AFAIK there is no option in Maven to drop it.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, our team decided to drop it as we are delivering a fat jar. And the `pom.xml` is quite messy and so we don't want to expose it to client / end-users. It will be internal, we are not exposing it to general public so Standards are flexible in this case.

Comment: You can use the flatten Maven plugin to remove the "mess" from the POM. And if you don't want a POM at all in the JAR, you probably need to write a shell script that removes it.

Comment: `you probably need to write a shell script that removes it.` we will give this a though !! tx.